# determine number of possible combinations having maximum element less than sum of remaining elements

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am provided with a value **m** , such that I have numbers from **1 to m** ,
and another number **n** **( n<=m)**  such that I can choose any **n numbers from given m numbers**. Now I need to calculate **number of total possible combinations** such that **the maximum of the selected n numbers is strictly less than the sum of remaining (n-1) numbers** .

**Example:-** m=5 ,n=3
We have (1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,4),(2,3,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,5),(2,3,5),(1,4,5),(2,4,5) and (3,4,5), out of which only (2,3,4),(2,4,5) and (3,4,5) are valid. So answer is 3.

I am not able to understand how to approach this. I have my exam tomorrow and this may be one of the questions . Please help .