# Need to evaluate the possible recurrence from the table

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinations

In continuation to my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563876/determine-number-of-possible-combinations-having-maximum-element-less-than-sum-o) posted yesterday ,I obtained one table on the basis of some initial values, and tried to observe some pattern out of it.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
0& & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \hline
 0&0 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\ \hline
 0 &0 & 0& & & & & & & & & & & & &\\ \hline
 0& 0& 1& 1& & & & & & & & & & & &\\ \hline
 0& 0& 3&5 &1 & & & & & & & & & & &\\ \hline
0& 0& 7&14 &6 &1 & & & & & & & & & &\\ \hline
0&0 &13 &32 &21 &7 &1 & & & & & & & & &\\ \hline
0& 0& 22&63 &56 &28 &8 &1 & & & & & & & &\\ \hline
0& 0& 34&112 &126 &84 &36 &9 &1 & & & & & & &\\ \hline
0& 0& 50&185 &251 &210 &120 &45 &10 &1 & & & & & &\\ \hline
0& 0& 70&289 &459 &462 &330 &165 &55 &11 &1 & & & & &\\ \hline
0& 0& 95& 431& 785&924&792 &495 &220 &66 &12 &1 & & & &\\ \hline
0& 0&125 &620 &1273 &1716 &1716 &1287 &715 &286 &78 &13 &1 & & &\\ \hline
0& 0& 161& 865& 1976& 3003&3432 &3003 &2002 &1001 &364 &91 &14 &1 & &\\ \hline
0& 0& 203&1176 &2959 &5004 &6435 &6435 &5005 &3003 &1365 &455 &105 &15 &1 &\\ \hline
0&0 &252 &1564 &4297 &8005 &11440 &12870 &11440 &8008 &4368 &1820 &560 &120 &16 &1\\ \hline
\end{array}

Based on the above mentioned table , i observed that as we move towards right half of table f(i,j)=f(i-1,j-1)+f(i-1,j) . Can someone help me out using this to derive any recurrence if it exists?

Comment: Your observation is just the formula ${m\choose n} = {m-1\choose n-1}+{m-1\choose n}$. As $m,n$ grows large the initial terms of your columns would just be ${m\choose n}$ but this does not generally holds because you have the restriction that the largest number is less then the sum of remaining numbers. When the restriction start to take effect your recurrence will not hold any more.

Comment: then what is the way to solve it.. obviously there must be some way to do it.. no one can simply list down all solutions and keep checking like this..